# ad library returns empty result

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The ad library API returns empty json "data". Here is the session: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/855225802904868/?session_id=796283358919122

I've got my app key from my app and tried get the information from ad library but got empty results. Maybe someone knows or had some experience in that area?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJzXT.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.